# How To Create a Loop With Pandas and PyAutoGui.Write

Tags: python, pandas

I am using pyautogui to create a simple bot. However, in that bot, there is a point where I need to input information from a csv file individually and click "go". I have figured out how to do this indivudally with each row/column.

This is basically what I am using:

```
def function1():

    df = pd.read_csv('dbc.csv', header=None)
    doThisFirst()
    pyautogui.write(df.iloc[1, 0])
    thenDoThis()
    pyautogui.write(df.iloc[1, 1])
    ClickStuff()
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    sleep(for a bit of time)
```

Then the same for the next row.

Let's say there are 100 rows, I definitely do not want to write out up to function 100.

I have searched around and although I can find "some things" similar, I can't figure out how to write (df.iloc[nextrow, 0/1]) until the rows no longer have data.

I have thought of while true, or for i in df, and was able to get a "loop" working, but because it keeps writing the same row/columns, I haven't been able to test if it stops when there are no more rows.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it by just adding a for loop in the beginning:

```
def function1():
    for i in range(1, len(df)): # This will get executed for every row
        df = pd.read_csv('dbc.csv', header=None)
        doThisFirst()
        pyautogui.write(df.iloc[i, 0])
        thenDoThis()
        pyautogui.write(df.iloc[i, 1])
        ClickStuff()
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        sleep(for a bit of time)
```

Comment: Oh that looks good, I am going to fire up the computer when I get off work and give it a shot. Then I will update. I appreciate the reply and help.

Comment: This worked great except I had to take the df declaration out of the loop and declare it before I started the loop. E.G. df= this.stuff and then for i in range

Comment: I super appreciate the help